# WPF Control inside a transparent winform is not displayed

Tags: wpf, interop, transparency

I create a simple WPF UserControl (any control will do) and insert it into a Winform (using an ElementHost).
This works fine. The WPF control is embedded in the WinForm and when the WinForm is moved around the WPF control moves with it just like a WinForm control will do.
When I change the WinForm to transparent by setting the TranparencyKey to the same value as the BackColor some problems occur:
- The WPF control is not displayed - instead a black rectangle is displayed in its place..
- If the WinForm is moved around the screen then on its original place the WPF control appears - as if it was covered by the WinForm.

Changing properties of the ElementHost (such as BackColorTransparent) did not change the behavior.
Setting both the BackColor and the TransparencyKey of the WinForm to Black got rid of the black rectangle problem but still when the WinForm was moved the WPF control was left in the original place.

Note also that these problems occurs under Windows XP SP3 (which is our target OS) but not on Windows 2003.
(We did not check on Vista and Windows 7).

Any ideas how to have a transparent Winform with a WPF control inside and still get a normal behavior?

Comment: Did you check on different XP computers (with different graphics hardware)? things like this are often graphics driver bugs.

Comment: I also ran into this problem, would be interested in the solution as well.

Comment: I tested on 2 XP computers with different HW and got the same results. I suspect this has nothing to do with HW but is related to WinForm & WPF Interop.

Comment: I have the same question too. I'm in the need of making the form transparent but still keeping child controls opaque

Comment: What do you want to do with this form!

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the background property on the WPF control?  By default it inherits from it's parent container and if it's not present it will do this.  Try setting the background property on the UserControl to white or grey and your problem should go away.